# Setting different colors in text browser

Tags: qt

I get a file via http get from the server which is a diff file.
I want to set the text color red for removed and green for added maybe looking for the first character < / >.
How to do that in Qt?

```
> 10 permit ip 10.10.0.0/16 20.20.20.0/24
> 20 deny ip any any
34,35c28
< 10 permit ip 10.10.10.4/30 20.20.20.0/31
< 20 permit ip 10.10.10.0/29 20.20.20.0/30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QTextBrowser`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html) class to show your contents. It supports `HTML`, so you can use some `HTML` code to change the color of specific text.

Something you need to note, is that [`HTML` uses `<` and `>` characters for tags](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). So we have to tell it that these are not tags, but characters we wish to display on the screen.

Here is a small example I made to show how you could do this:

```
QStringList text_list; // I use this to store lines of text
text_list << "> Added this row";
text_list << "> Added this row";
text_list << "< Removed this row";
text_list << "> Added this row";

//the following string is what we will use to style our text
QString html_style("<style>"
                         "p.add{color: green; margin: 0; padding: 0;}"
                         "p.remove{color: red; margin: 0; padding: 0;}"
                         "</style>");

QString format_add = "<p class=\"add\">%1</p>"; // we use these to make formatting easier
QString format_remove = "<p class=\"remove\">%1</p>"; // basically helps us add tags before and after our text

QString text; // this is a variable we will use to append our text as HTML code

for(int i = 0; i < text_list.length(); i++)
{
    if(text_list[i].startsWith(">")) // detect if the line was added
        text.append(format_add.arg(text_list[i].replace(">", "&#62;"))); // add the line in our html code, but replace > character with a character entity

    else if(text_list[i].startsWith("<")) // detect if the line was removed
        text.append(format_remove.arg(text_list[i].replace("<", "&#60;"))); // add the line in our html code, but replace < character with a character entity
}

ui->textBrowser->setHtml(html_style + text);
```

Comment: Thanks! I currently have a QByteArray and not a QStringList. Can I convert it?

Comment: @SahilSareen It doesn't matter. I just used `QStringList` because it was simple. As long as you can get a string out of it, it doesn't matter where you store it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>` html tag to set a color for part of text :

```
QString styledString="<span style=\" font-size:8pt; font-weight:600; color:#FF0c32;\" > ";
styledString.append(myString);
styledString.append("</span>");

textBrowser->setHtml(styledString);
```